# Scalability and Thread Safety of Application Scoped ManagedBean Methods

Tags: jsf

During testing a weakness was exposed in how our app builds `f:selectItems` lists, specifically, entering really long names on some of our entities screws page alignment by making really wide selects.

Many of these selectItem lists are duplicated in multiple views and backing beans, so I'd like to consolidate their creation.

We already have an application scoped bean that provides List<SelectItem> for enums, and my initial thought was to place them there.

I have some questions, though.  We're using jsf 1.2 (if that matters)

1) My understanding is that application scoped beans are singleton simply because a single instance is instantiated and placed in session context.  They are not like EJB3 singletons in that only one thread can access any method, so multiple requests won't block trying to access different methods.  Is that correct?

2) I suspect each method would have to be synchronized to prevent multiple threads calling the same method from clobbering each other.  Is that the case even if the only class member accessed in the method is a threadsafe stateless @EJB?

Following is an implementation of one of them that would be used in 20 views.  The implementations for 10 other entities would be similar.  Also, the appropriate converters are registered.

```
public synchronized List<SelectItem> getAccountSelect(){
    List<Account> list = new ArrayList<Account>(pemEJB.list(Account.class));
    Collections.sort(list, new AccountByActiveByName());
    List<SelectItem> result=new ArrayList<SelectItem>(list.size());
    for(Account row : list){
        result.add(new SelectItem(row, 
                StringUtil.prefixTruncate(row.getName(), MAX_ACCT_LENGTH, row.isActive())));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Any advice appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's really mandatory to do the data loading in a getter instead of in the constructor/postconstruct, then there's definitely no point of making it an application scoped bean. Just make it a request scoped one where you do the data loading job in the constructor/postconstruct.

Comment: Thanks, the light bulb just went off.  I was stuck in a beans back views mindset and never considered simply using a separate single request bean from all the views

Answer (score 2):

In the jsf applications I work on we load almost all of our reference data (values for selectOneMenues primarily) in Application scope beans and we set up the values in the Constructor of those beans. The data is then available to other managed beans and views via getters but is globalized and centralized for the application. Since the values are only read via getters there is no need for synchronization.

We then expose the beans as mbeans through jmx with a reload method so that they can be updated as needed. The reload method(s) are synchronized so as to block during the short reloads.

In your example above it seems like you could just return a Collection of selectItems so as long as the values are setup in advance you can use this method and still serve multiple threads just fine:

```
public List<SelectItem> getAccountSelectItems() {
    return this.accountSelectItems;
}
```

Just add this private member to your bean:

```
private List<SelectItem> accountSelectItems;
```

and set it up in the constructor:

```
public AccountBean() {
    List<Account> list = new ArrayList<Account>(pemEJB.list(Account.class));
    Collections.sort(list, new AccountByActiveByName());
    this.accountSelectItems = new ArrayList<SelectItem>(list.size());

    for(Account row : list) {
        this.accountSelectItems.add(new SelectItem(row, StringUtil.prefixTruncate(row.getName(), MAX_ACCT_LENGTH, row.isActive())));
    }
}
```

If on the other hand this is data that is constantly changing and needs to be updated you might be better off just loading it per session or per request, though you can reload it periodically in application scope using Quartz or some other timer to keep the data reads from your data source down if real time is not an essential requirement for this data in your app. If you are reloading the data then you will want to synchronize those operations if you're using application scope.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's a requirement to build on request.  I think a separate request scoped bean is the way to go.